# RoR - Create user on create and not when user goes to New page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up my rails app so that when a user goes to www.example.com/personal_messages/new , it doesn't create a new account, but rather when the user submits it. But problem is that I will get an error if I move the User.create function. Is there a workaround to this?

personal_messages controller

```
class PersonalMessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_receiver!, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation) and return if @conversation
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conversation ||= Conversation.create(author_id: cookies[:user_id],
                                         receiver_id: @receiver)
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build(personal_message_params)
    @personal_message.conversation_id = @conversation.id
    @personal_message.save!

    flash[:success] = "ok!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

  def personal_message_params
    params.require(:personal_message).permit(:body)
  end

  def check_receiver!
    @ip = request.remote_ip
    if cookies[:user_id].blank?
     @user = User.create(email: "thinkrtcvisitor-#{rand(999999)}@visitor.com", ip_address: @ip, password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678')
       @user.save!
        cookies.permanent[:user_id] = @user.id
        cookies.permanent[:current_user_cookie] = User.find_by_id(cookies[:user_id])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
   end
    @receiver = cookies[:site_id]
    @conversation = Conversation.between(cookies[:user_id], @receiver)[0]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.new
```

instead of

```
@personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build
```

in your `new` action.

Comment: This seems to work somewhat, but now the users aren't being redirected when they go to /personal_messages/new

EDIT: Also, i tried @personal_message = PersonalMmessage.new and this works.

Comment: `build` and `new` are just aliases, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/build